# Add user to group which can access network interfaces

Tags: networking, user-management

I am currently setting up an IDS (suricata), which currently only runs as sudo due to when running as a user it cannot access/change the network interface settings.

Is there a way you add a user to a group which can access network interfaces or is there an alternative secure solution which solve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo gpasswd -a yourusername netdev
```

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1301414&p=8167414#post8167414)

Answer (score 1):

try adding the user to "netdev" group using usermod command instead of useradd command. Note that user must be an existing user. I have done this myself on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it works:

```
sudo usermod -a -G netdev <user>
```

after this command, check whether user got added by doing:

```
id <user>
```

if not added, try restarting/logging out and do above command (id) again

**WARNING: do NOT omit '-a' in first command. Be careful**

Comment: I tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and it does not work. Error: `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @SuB maybe the user is already part of netdev. Type 'groups' or 'id' in terminal to find whether current user is part of netdev group

Comment: It deos not belogn to `netdev` group. the error occurs when i'm running `ifconfig eth0 up` not when i'm running `usermod`

Comment: type     id in terminal and check whether current user is part of     netdev group

Comment: Yes. I've added it to `netdev` group but error is shown.

Comment: Try this. Firstly, do `ifconfig -a` and check whether an interface named **eth0** really exists. If it does, do `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` .  Then do `sudo ifconfig eth0 down`

Answer (score 1):

You can permit a user to run specific tool with `root` privilege by editing `/etc/sudoers` file. For example you can permit a non-root non-sudoer user to run only `ifconfig` command, so he/she can't access root privileged things like viewing `/etc/shadow`.

So, create a normal user (**MYUSER** in my example). Don't add it to `root` or `sudo` groups. Edit `/etc/sudoers` with your favorite editor like `vim`. Add this line under `# User privilege specification`:

```
MYUSER    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD :/sbin/ifconfig *
```

Then access `ifconfig` using `sudo` when logged in as **MYUSER**. For example:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

Replace `ifconfig` in this answer with any tool you want like `tcpdump`, `tshark`, etc.

Reference is [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/suse-linux/180235-how-allow-user-change-ip-address-without-root-password-post850430.html?s=f942b7b2ebff2bc597e9fc797a9806b6#post850430).

Answer (score 0):

Add user to the "netdev" group:

```
useradd -G netdev dedunud
```

Comment: Tried that I did "sudo usermod -a -G netdev myuser" but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In Wireshark, there is a group which users can be added to in order to capture packets, for example. This had to be implemented. (Unless I misremembered)

Maybe you could combine the IDS with tshark / wireshark.

Otherwise, it could be a bit harder (maybe see how they did that?)