# Allow non-root users to access virtual ethernet devices in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ethernet

I've created a virtual ethernet tunnel with `ip` like so:

```
$ sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
```

I want to be able to use these devices (in C, not from a shell command) without running as root.

I've seen other suggestions floating around that suggest adding the user to the `netdev` group (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341810/add-user-to-group-which-can-access-network-interfaces/856260) question), but this doesn't appear to be valid for Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Other than running in a container/VM, is there any way to relax the permissions for these virtual interfaces?

Comment: @tatsu Creating the tunnel with `ip link` doesn't actually create files or anything under `/dev`, so there isn't anything there for me to `chmod` or `chown`. The devices can be seen with `ip a`.

Comment: alright. my assumption was that it would.